# How to debug ios8 share extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

I tried two ways to debug while the extension is running:

a. using NSlog, such as

```
    NSLog(@"%@", ((NSExtensionItem *)self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject).userInfo);
```

but no log shows.

b. using code like

```
    p self.extensionContext
```

in the lldb debug mode, but it tells me

```
    error: property 'extensionContext' not found on object of type 'ShareViewController *'
    error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use simulator debug. On Simulator, click on Debug Menu, Open System Log.

Comment: I totally disagree, we can debug in even in iPhone as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001916/3632832

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned **[HERE](http://easynativeextensions.com/how-to-debug-your-ios-extension/)**, you can debug share extension by attaching target

> Debug ->  Attach Process -> By process name or PID

[image]

In our case, PID will be Share extension bundle name as mentioned in Share Extension Target.